# select th assigned to a specific column

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Assume we have this html:

```
<table>
    <caption>test</caption>
    <colgroup>
        <col class='col1'/>
        <col class='col2'/>
        <col class='col3'/>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell1.1</td>
            <td>Coll1.2</td>
            <td>Coll1.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell2.1</td>
            <td>Coll2.2</td>
            <td>Coll2.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell3.1</td>
            <td>Coll3.2</td>
            <td>Coll3.3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And we have this CSS:

```
.col2{
    background-color: #AAA;
}
.col1,col3{
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Now I want to select the `th` that is associated with `col2` column to put a background image on it.
Something like `.col2:th` or `th.col2` or `.col2 th` , ...

I want to select `th` but by addressing from `col` element;
I'm setting the class on `col` and it is dynamic so I want to access `th` by `col` element and not directly
How can I select specific tags that are associated with specific `col` tag with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is confusing me a but, are you trying to target second `th` which is nested inside `thead` element? If yes, than this is the selector which you are looking for

```
table thead tr th:nth-of-type(2) { /* Targets 2nd table head */
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2TQ2k/)

---

As per your comment, the answer is **No**, you cannot do that with pure CSS, you cannot pop out of the `colgroup` to select an element in `thead`

Comment: Yes and no; I want to select second `th` but by addressing from `col` element; I'm setting the class on `col` and it is dynamic so I want to access `th` by `col` element and not directly

Comment: @4r1y4n No, you cannot do that with pure CSS, you cannot pop out of the colgroup to select an element in `thead`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:-

```
thead tr th:nth-of-type(2)

{
 // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the header being selected is always the second one (sounds like the css is dynamic, not which column, but i could be wrong) you could always use id.

```
<th id="header2">Column2</th>
```

and then simply add the stuff you want in your css under that hash

```
#header2{
     background-image: url('foobar.png');
}
```